# How to hide ajax requests from browser's console and firebug console?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to hide ajax call requests from console.I have tried using clearconsole function as below,

```
function clearconsole() { 
    console.log(window.console);
    if(window.console || window.console.firebug) {
    console.clear();
    }
}
```

It's working for browser's console but not for firebug console.How to make it work for firebug too.

Comment: Note that in Google Chrome, console.clear() has no effect if the user has selected "Preserve log upon navigation" in the settings.

Comment: Can we do something irrespective of settings

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

```
    if (! ('console' in window) || !('firebug' in console)) {
        var names = ['log', 'debug', 'info', 'warn', 'error', 'assert', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'group', 'groupEnd', 'time', 'timeEnd', 'count', 'trace', 'profile', 'profileEnd'];
        window.console = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; ++i) window.console[names[i]] = function() {};
    }
```

I found from this original article : [how-to-sniff-firebug-disable](https://davidwalsh.name/how-to-sniff-firebug-disable)

Comment: thanks @mrJ0ul3, this is not working for all versions of firebug